# Are there any known parametric equations for the club and spade suits on playing cards?

Tags: graphing-functions

Just out of curiosity, so that I could plot them in a program. I am able to plot diamonds using superellipses and Wolfram Mathworld has some good equations for hearts. I can't find anything for clubs or spades, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX has the four suit glyphs,  in font `cmsy`.  You can find the code in

> *Knuth, Donald E.*, Computer Modern typefaces, Computers & Typesetting. Vol. E. Reading, Massachusetts etc.: Addison Wesley Publishing Company. XV, 588 p. (1986). [ZBL0609.68005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0609.68005).

and see what equations were used for these shapes.  Unlike most font designers, Knuth published his source code.

[image]

Comment: In the book he doesn't give equations, just points and how to fill in between those points using calligraphic functions